# When do you say "informed from" instead of "informed by"? Is there any difference in nuance?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, passive-voice, phrase-choice

When we describe something in a passive voice sentence, we often add in it "by" + "someone/something" to indicate who or what the doer of the action is.

Example
(Active Voice) The hunter killed the lion.
(Passive Voice) The lion was killed **by** the hunter.

"By", however, is not the only preposition to refer to the doer in a passive voice sentence.

Example

> [Famous American TV host Larry King has died at 87, ARMENPRESS was
> informed **from** King's official Twitter page.](https://armenpress.am/eng/news/1041219/)

> [The Embassy was informed **from** reliable sources that ...](https://history.state.gov/historicaldocuments/frus1933v02/d235)

In my [Ngram Viewer search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20informed%20by%2Cwas%20informed%20from&year_start=1990&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20informed%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20informed%20from%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwas%20informed%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20informed%20from%3B%2Cc0) for the two phrases "was informed by" and "was informed from" tells that the former is much popular.
[image]

Is there any difference in nuance between the two phrases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your examples as meaning

> The Embassy was informed (from reliable sources) that ...

Then prepositional phrase isn't functioning to indicate the agent in a passive voice.  It is parenthetical.

However in both quoted examples, "by" would have been better and clearer

Answer (score 1):

To me, "informed from" sounds like a bad word choice. Both of your examples sound as if they should use "by".